# Why am I getting a docker-compose version conflict on a fully updated azerothcore download?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos, azerothcore

OS: `CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)  [3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64]`

Have done a `yum upgrade/update` and nothing left to update, have also just completed a `git pull` for `azerothcore-wotlk` and nothing left to update there, either.

```
[azerothcore-wotlk]$ docker-compose up
```

> ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
>   For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

```
[azerothcore-wotlk]$ head docker-compose.yml
version: '3.2'

services:

  ac-database:
    image: azerothcore/database
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/database/Dockerfile
    networks:
```

```
[azerothcore-wotlk]$ docker-compose --version

docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
```

```
[azerothcore-wotlk]$ docker --version

Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that, in spite of getting a return for this user's `docker-compose --version`, it hadn't installed globally?

So the fix for me was:

1) `sudo yum install docker-compose`  -- this grabbed 1.18 for a global install

2) `sudo docker-compose --version`    -- this now returns 1.18

3) `sudo docker-compose up`           -- now is working.